# Gesture triggers exception in subview of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

Novice iOS programmer here, so sorry if I'm missing something easy, but...

I have a UIViewController class called **LVSTSPMasterViewController** whose view was built in IB. The view contains a UIScrollView (added in IB) and that scroll view has a subview of type **LVSTSPView**. **LVSTSPView** has a controller of type **LVSTSPViewController**.

I want to respond to touches in the **LVSTSPView**, so I added gesture recognizers to **LVSTSPViewController.m**. When I execute the gesture (e.g., do a long press), the code crashes with message "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=...)" in **main.m**.

Relevant code:

In **LVSAppDelegate.m**:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Get pointer to app bundle
    NSBundle *appBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

    // Get xib file
    LVSTSPMasterViewController *tspmvc = [[LVSTSPMasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LVSTSPMasterViewController" bundle:appBundle];

    self.window.rootViewController = tspmvc;

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

In **LVSMasterViewController.m**:

```
@interface LVSTSPMasterViewController () <UIScrollViewDelegate>

// IBOutlet declarations

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIScrollView *TSPScrollView;

// Pointers for convenience

@property (strong, nonatomic) LVSTSPView *TSPView;

@end

@implementation LVSTSPMasterViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Create LVSTSPViewController
    LVSTSPViewController *tspvc = [[LVSTSPViewController alloc] init];

    // Set up pointer to LVSTSPView
    self.TSPView = (LVSTSPView *)tspvc.view;

    // Set frame of LVSTSPView
    self.TSPView.frame = self.TSPScrollView.bounds;

    // Set tspvc's view as subview of TSPScrollView
    [self.TSPScrollView addSubview:tspvc.view];

    // Set up scroll view
    self.TSPScrollView.pagingEnabled = NO;
    self.TSPScrollView.contentSize = self.TSPView.frame.size;
    self.TSPScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    self.TSPScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0;

    // Set scroll view's delegate property
    self.TSPScrollView.delegate = self;
}
```

In **LVSTSPViewController.m**:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    // Create view
    LVSTSPView *view = [[LVSTSPView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    self.view = view;

    // Long-press recognizer
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *pressRecognizer =
        [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:pressRecognizer];
}

- (void)longPress:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gr
{
    NSLog(@"longPress:");

}
```

One other note: If I set up the gesture recognizer in `viewDidLoad:` in **LVSTSPMasterViewController.m**, like so --

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *pressRecognizer =
    [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
[self.TSPView addGestureRecognizer:pressRecognizer];
```

-- (and of course add `longPress:` to **LVSTSPMasterViewController.m**), then it works. But this doesn't seem like the right approach since the **LVSTSPMasterViewController** is not the view controller for **LVSTSPView**.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view controller LVSTSPViewController is not retained anywhere or in other words your master view controller needs to retain it.
In **LVSMasterViewController.m**, change your code to

```
@implementation LVSTSPMasterViewController
{
   LVSTSPViewController *tspvc;//creates strong reference to self(LVSTSPMasterViewController)
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
  tspvc = [[LVSTSPViewController alloc] init];

  // Set up pointer to LVSTSPView
  self.TSPView = (LVSTSPView *)tspvc.view;

  // Set frame of LVSTSPView
  self.TSPView.frame = self.TSPScrollView.bounds;

  // Set tspvc's view as subview of TSPScrollView
  [self.TSPScrollView addSubview:tspvc.view];

  // Set up scroll view
  self.TSPScrollView.pagingEnabled = NO;
  self.TSPScrollView.contentSize = self.TSPView.frame.size;
  self.TSPScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
  self.TSPScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0;

  // Set scroll view's delegate property
  self.TSPScrollView.delegate = self;
}
```

Also always call *[super viewDidLoad]* first in your *viewDidLoad* method. I would suggest to read more about view and view controller in the apple documentation. You necessarily do not need a view controller with every view. It all depends on your specific case. One view controller can manage multiple views.

Comment: Thanks @codingBuddha -- this worked. What is the name for the way you declared tspvc right after `@implementation`? I do need a VC here, by the way, but thanks for that tip. As for _[super viewDidLoad]_, I knew that but forgot. :\

Comment: That is nothing but defining instance variable without a property.
[see this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW4)